# How can i get the title i specified in add_options_page for my header

Tags: plugin-development

i have

```
add_options_page('Post Products Settings', 'Post Products Settings', 'administrator', 'pp_settings', 'pp_settings_page');
```

anyway i can get whats specified in the 1st parameter for use in my page header? i know i can hard code it tho, but just curious

Comment: That first parameter *will* be your page title ... Have you tested this code?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish and what are you seeing that's not the behavior you want?

Comment: Yeah we need some more information to really help you generate the code to solve your problem.

Comment: In your page callback function you have to output a h1 or h2 inside the page content itself. The question is how to fetch that string programatically instead of duplicating it.

Comment: yes jeremy is right. i am wondering if there is any way i can get what is entered in the 1st parameter by code so i can output it in the h2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this. My preferred way of doing this is using Object Oriented Programming (OOP) to structure the plugin. For example, I might do this:

```
class JPBTitle {
  var $page_title = "Post Products Settings";

  function __construct(){
    add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'admin_menu' ) );
  }

  function admin_menu(){
    add_options_page( $this->page_title, $this->page_title, 'administrator', 'pp_settings', array( $this, 'pp_settings' ) );
  }

  function pp_settings(){
    echo "<div class='wrap'>\n\t<h2>$this->page_title</h2></div>";
  }
}

$JPBTitle = new JPBTitle();
```

There are many many advantages to using object oriented programming in plugins; however, if you don't want to use OOP, I would suggest either setting a global variable or defining a constant with the value you want to use for that string.

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`get_admin_page_title()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L1283). If the global variable `$title` is not empty it will return that, otherwise it will set it and return the value.

It is called at the top of [`admin-header.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-admin/admin-header.php) and then goes through `esc_html()`, so if you want the raw value you should empty `$title` and call the function again.